# Accessing other form fields in a custom Django upload handler

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I've written a custom Django file upload handler for my current project. It's a proof-of-concept which allows you to compute a hash of an uploaded file without storing that file on-disk. It's a proof of concept, to be sure, but if I can get it to work, I can get onto the real purpose of my work.

Essentially, here's what I have so far, which is working fine with one major exception:

```
from django.core.files.uploadhandler import *
from hashlib import sha256
from myproject.upload.files import MyProjectUploadedFile

class MyProjectUploadHandler(FileUploadHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyProjectUploadHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def handle_raw_input(self, input_data, META, content_length, boundary,
            encoding = None):
        self.activated = True

    def new_file(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyProjectUploadHandler, self).new_file(*args, **kwargs)

        self.digester = sha256()
        raise StopFutureHandlers()

    def receive_data_chunk(self, raw_data, start):
        self.digester.update(raw_data)

    def file_complete(self, file_size):
        return MyProjectUploadedFile(self.digester.hexdigest())
```

The custom upload handler works great. The hash is accurate and works without storing any of the uploaded file to disk and only uses 64kb of memory at any one time.

The only problem I'm having is that I need to access another field from the POST request before processing the file, a text salt input by the user. My form looks like this:

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/">
    <fieldset>
        <input name="salt" type="text" placeholder="Salt">
        <input name="uploadfile" type="file">
        <input type="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The "salt" POST variable is only made available to me after the request has been processed and the file has been uploaded, which doesn't work for my use case. I can't seem to find a way to access this variable in any way, shape, or form in my upload handler.

Is there a way for me to access each multipart variable as it comes across instead of just accessing the filess which are uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution didn't come easy, but here it is:

```
class IntelligentUploadHandler(FileUploadHandler):
    """
    An upload handler which overrides the default multipart parser to allow
    simultaneous parsing of fields and files... intelligently. Subclass this
    for real and true awesomeness.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IntelligentUploadHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def field_parsed(self, field_name, field_value):
        """
        A callback method triggered when a non-file field has been parsed 
        successfully by the parser. Use this to listen for new fields being
        parsed.
        """
        pass

    def handle_raw_input(self, input_data, META, content_length, boundary,
            encoding = None):
        """
        Parse the raw input from the HTTP request and split items into fields
        and files, executing callback methods as necessary.

        Shamelessly adapted and borrowed from django.http.multiparser.MultiPartParser.
        """
        # following suit from the source class, this is imported here to avoid
        # a potential circular import
        from django.http import QueryDict

        # create return values
        self.POST = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
        self.FILES = MultiValueDict()

        # initialize the parser and stream
        stream = LazyStream(ChunkIter(input_data, self.chunk_size))

        # whether or not to signal a file-completion at the beginning of the loop.
        old_field_name = None
        counter = 0

        try:
            for item_type, meta_data, field_stream in Parser(stream, boundary):
                if old_field_name:
                    # we run this test at the beginning of the next loop since
                    # we cannot be sure a file is complete until we hit the next
                    # boundary/part of the multipart content.
                    file_obj = self.file_complete(counter)

                    if file_obj:
                        # if we return a file object, add it to the files dict
                        self.FILES.appendlist(force_text(old_field_name, encoding,
                            errors='replace'), file_obj)

                    # wipe it out to prevent havoc
                    old_field_name = None
                try: 
                    disposition = meta_data['content-disposition'][1]
                    field_name = disposition['name'].strip()
                except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):
                    continue

                transfer_encoding = meta_data.get('content-transfer-encoding')

                if transfer_encoding is not None:
                    transfer_encoding = transfer_encoding[0].strip()

                field_name = force_text(field_name, encoding, errors='replace')

                if item_type == FIELD:
                    # this is a POST field
                    if transfer_encoding == "base64":
                        raw_data = field_stream.read()
                        try:
                            data = str(raw_data).decode('base64')
                        except:
                            data = raw_data
                    else:
                        data = field_stream.read()

                    self.POST.appendlist(field_name, force_text(data, encoding,
                        errors='replace'))

                    # trigger listener
                    self.field_parsed(field_name, self.POST.get(field_name))
                elif item_type == FILE:
                    # this is a file
                    file_name = disposition.get('filename')

                    if not file_name:
                        continue

                    # transform the file name
                    file_name = force_text(file_name, encoding, errors='replace')
                    file_name = self.IE_sanitize(unescape_entities(file_name))

                    content_type = meta_data.get('content-type', ('',))[0].strip()

                    try:
                        charset = meta_data.get('content-type', (0, {}))[1].get('charset', None)
                    except:
                        charset = None

                    try:
                        file_content_length = int(meta_data.get('content-length')[0])
                    except (IndexError, TypeError, ValueError):
                        file_content_length = None

                    counter = 0

                    # now, do the important file stuff
                    try:
                        # alert on the new file
                        self.new_file(field_name, file_name, content_type,
                                file_content_length, charset)

                        # chubber-chunk it
                        for chunk in field_stream:
                            if transfer_encoding == "base64":
                                # base 64 decode it if need be
                                over_bytes = len(chunk) % 4

                                if over_bytes:
                                    over_chunk = field_stream.read(4 - over_bytes)
                                    chunk += over_chunk

                                try:
                                    chunk = base64.b64decode(chunk)
                                except Exception as e:
                                    # since this is anly a chunk, any error is an unfixable error
                                    raise MultiPartParserError("Could not decode base64 data: %r" % e)

                            chunk_length = len(chunk)
                            self.receive_data_chunk(chunk, counter)
                            counter += chunk_length
                            # ... and we're done
                    except SkipFile:
                        # just eat the rest
                        exhaust(field_stream)
                    else:
                        # handle file upload completions on next iteration
                        old_field_name = field_name

        except StopUpload as e:
            # if we get a request to stop the upload, exhaust it if no con reset
            if not e.connection_reset:
                exhaust(input_data)
        else:
            # make sure that the request data is all fed
            exhaust(input_data)

        # signal the upload has been completed
        self.upload_complete()

        return self.POST, self.FILES

    def IE_sanitize(self, filename):
        """Cleanup filename from Internet Explorer full paths."""
        return filename and filename[filename.rfind("\\")+1:].strip()
```

Essentially, by subclassing this class, you can have a more... intelligent upload handler. Fields will be announced with the `field_parsed` method to subclasses, as I needed for my purposes.

I've reported this as a [feature request](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20034) to the Django team, hopefully this functionality becomes a part of the regular toolbox in Django, rather than monkey-patching the source code as done above.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code for `FileUploadHandler`, found here at line 62:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/uploadhandler.py

It looks like the request object is passed into the handler and stored as `self.request`

In that case you should be able to access the salt at any point in your upload handler by doing

```
salt = self.request.POST.get('salt')
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: That's the problem, your code doesn't work. If I `print self.request.REQUEST`, I get `{}` in my console, essentially no vars are available until after the handler is done.

Comment: If I get my hands dirty with `handle_raw_input`, I can read the actual request body, variable data and all. I'd like to know if there's a better solution for this, however, as it's a bit cumbersome to work with the data manually, parsing boundaries, extracting variable information, etc.